# Installing the deb package via ansible

Tags: ansible, deb

I am trying to install a deb package on a remote server using ansible, using the following construction

```
- name: Install deb
  delegate_to: app1
  apt:
    deb: https://example.com/deb/package.deb
```

or

```
- name: Install deb
  delegate_to: app1
  apt:
    deb: /path/to/deb
```

playbook works, says that everything is ok, but in fact the package is not installed, if you connect to a remote server and manually run `apt install /path/to/deb`, then the package is installed. I tried to copy deb to the server using ansible and install it by downloading the package from an Internet resource, the result is always the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modification of the task helped

```
- name: Install deb
  command: apt install /path/to/package.deb -y --allow-downgrades
```

The allow_downgrade directive for the apt module appeared, starting with the ansible 2.12 version in my 2.9 it did not work, as the force directive did not work, I had to implement the task using a not very nice method.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) methods `become` and `become_method: sudo` for Ansible. Installing a package need `sudo` privilege.

```
- name: Install deb
  delegate_to: app1
  apt:
    deb: /path/to/deb
  become: true
```

Comment: I use the -b switch, isn't that enough?

Comment: yes, -b should work.